# where to find historical ticker data for securities no longer in s&p 500 index?

Tags: equities, historical-data, sp500

im looking for the complete intraday ticker data time-series for a number of securities that formerly were part of the s&p 500 index. eg.

PGN, Progress Energy Inc, removed from index 2012 because: Acquired by Duke Energy

wikipedia offers a list of some 250 former s&p 500 members. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies.

question:

do you know of any site from which the historical ticker data of these stocks may be downloaded? it must be free of charge and be available via an api that does not require manual interaction for each request (ie. it should be accessible "programatically").

alphavanta.co *does* work for all current members/securities, eg. GOOGL:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=GOOGL&interval=5min&apikey=%demo%27&datatype=csv

but does not seem to work for former members, eg. PGN:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=PGN&interval=5min&apikey=%demo%27&datatype=csv

thanks for any suggestions and apologies if this is not the correct community for this question. in that case, please indicate which is.

Comment: Most data services delete these tickers once they are no longer in use, only a few keep them in a special 'historical' file and then sell the data to you for a high price.

Answer (score 5):

Hate to disappoint, but you're going to need to pay to get delisted securities.  Even basic equity price data of any quality comes with a cost.  There are a number of non-commercial vendors that include this sort of data with one of their packages though.

For instance, a vendor like Quandl (one of the cheapest, but still OK quality) offers packages for US equities that include delisted securities and run something like $60/month for a 5-year lookback with access via an API.